# Show convergence of $n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $(\Sigma_n)$ be a sequence of $r\times r$ positive definite matrices ($r$ fixed), and suppose that

$$A_n:=D_n^{1/2}\Sigma_nD_n^{1/2}\to A \quad \text{as} \quad n\to \infty,$$

for some positive definite matrix $A$, where convergence is with respect to the Frobenius norm, and $(D_n)$ is the sequence of diagonal matrices defined by

$$  D_n=\begin{bmatrix}
    n^{\kappa_1} & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & n^{\kappa_r}
  \end{bmatrix}$$
for some constants $0<\kappa_1<\dots<\kappa_r<1$.

**Question:** If $B$ is an $r\times r$ positive definite matrix, can I show that there exist constants $c_j>0$ such $n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j(B^{1/2}\Sigma_nB^{1/2})\to c_j$? ($\lambda_j(C)$ denotes the $j$th largest eigenvalue of symmetric matric $C$).

I made the following progress:

---

**Lemma.** There exist constants $c_j>0$ such $n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j(\Sigma_n)\to c_j$.

**Proof.** We have $n^{\kappa_j}D^{-1}_n=E_n+o(1)$ where

$$E_n:=\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}n^{\kappa_j-\kappa_i}e_ie_i^T+e_je_j^T$$ Since the sequence $A_n$ is bounded it follows that $$n^{\kappa_j}A^{1/2}_nD^{-1}_nA^{1/2}_n=A^{1/2}_nE_nA^{1/2}_n+o(1)$$ Then, using continuity of eigenvalues on the space of symmetric matrices (e.g. using  [Weyl's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) inequalities) we get

$$n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j(\Sigma_n)=n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j(D_n^{-1/2}A_nD_n^{-1/2})=n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j(A^{1/2}_nD^{-1}_nA^{1/2}_n)=\lambda_j(A^{1/2}_nE_nA_n^{1/2})+o(1)$$

Now we can use the same argument from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489234/522332) to obtain

$$\lambda_j(A^{1/2}_nE_nA_n^{1/2})\to c_j:= \frac{\det A[1:j,\,1:j]}{\det A[1:(j-1),\,1:(j-1)]}>0$$

---

Any ideas how to prove the statement, or a counterexample? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a **complete answer**. Using what you have shown, and the fact that $$\lambda_{\max}(B) \Sigma_n \succeq \Sigma_n^{\frac12}B\Sigma_n^{\frac12}\succeq \lambda_{\min}(B)\Sigma_n,$$ one can show easily that:

$$\lambda_{\max}(B) c_j \ge \limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j\left(B^{\frac12}\Sigma_nB^{\frac12}\right)\ge \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty} n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j\left(B^{\frac12}\Sigma_nB^{\frac12}\right) \ge \lambda_{\min} (B) c_j$$

with $c_j = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n^{\kappa_j}\lambda_j \left(\Sigma_n\right).$