# Show that this sequence of eigenvectors converge

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $A$ be a $3\times3 $ real positive definite matrix, and let $A_n=D_n^{1/2}AD_n^{1/2}$ where $D_n=diag(n,\sqrt{n},1)$. If $Q_nV_nQ_n'$ is an eigendecomposition of $A_n$, with $Q_n$ orthogonal and $V_n$ diagonal with elements decreasing order, can I show that

$$Q_n\to I_3 \quad \text{as} \quad n\to \infty \quad (\text{up to a column sign change})\quad?$$

**My attempt:** I will proceed in $3$ steps.

---

**Step1.** Note that $\lambda_j(A_n)=\lambda_j(A^{1/2}D_nA^{1/2})$, where $\lambda_j$ denotes the $j$th largest eigenvalue. Using the same argument as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489234/522332) we find that

$$\frac{1}{n}\lambda_1(A_n)\to a_{11}:=c_1>0$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lambda_2(A_n)\to \frac{\det(A[1:2,1:2])}{a_{11}}:=c_2>0$$

$$\lambda_3(A_n)\to \frac{\det(A[1:3,1:3])}{\det(A[1:2,1:2])}:=c_3>0$$

where $A[1:k,1:k]$ denotes the $k\times k$ upper left block of $A$. This implies that

$$Q_nV_n^{-1}Q_n-c^{-1}_3Q_ne_3e'_3Q_n'\to 0$$

Now, using the formula $B^{-1}=\det(B)^{-1}\text{adj}(B)$ we get

$$A_n^{-1}=D_n^{-1/2}A^{-1}D_n^{-1/2}\to e_3e_3'A^{-1}e_3e'_3=c^{-1}_3e_3e_3'$$

Since $A_n^{-1}=Q_nV_n^{-1}Q_n$ combining the previous two results gives

$$Q_ne_3e'_3Q_n\to e_3e_3'$$

Reading off the diagonal this means that

$$|Q^{(3,3)}_n|\to 1, \quad Q^{(3,j)}_n\to 0, \quad Q^{(j,3)}_n\to 0, \quad j\neq 3$$

---

**Step 2**. Since $Q'_nQ_n=Q_nQ'_n=I_3$, using the result from step 1 and block matrix multiplication we get, with $R_n:=Q_n[1:2,1:2]$,

$$R'_nR_n\to I_2, \quad R_nR'_n\to I_2 $$

Similarly, since $Q_nV_nQ'_n=A_n$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lambda_3(A_n)\to 0$, block multiplication gives, with $S_n:=V_n[1:2,1:2]$,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}R_nS_nR_n'-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}A_n[1:2,1:2]\to 0$$

Now note that $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}A_n[1:2,1:2])^{-1}\to e_2e_2'A^{-1}[1:2,1:2]e_2e_2'$ and $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}S_n)^{-1}\to c_2^{-1}e_2e'_2$. We then have the following chain of implications

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}R_nS_nR_n'-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}A_n[1:2,1:2]\to 0$$

$$\implies (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}A_n[1:2,1:2])^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}R_nS_nR_n'-I_2\to 0$$

$$\implies (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}A_n[1:2,1:2])^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}R_nS_n-R_n\to 0 \quad (\text{since $(A_n[1:2,1:2])^{-1} $ and $S_n$ are bounded and $R'_nR_n\to I_2$} )$$

$$\implies (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}A_n[1:2,1:2])^{-1} R_n-R_n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}S_n)^{-1}\to 0 $$

$$\implies (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}A_n[1:2,1:2])^{-1} -R_n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}S_n)^{-1}R'_n\to 0 \quad (\text{since $R_nR'_n\to I_2$}) $$

$$\implies c_2^{-1}R_ne_2e'_2R'_n\to  e_2e_2'A^{-1}[1:2,1:2]e_2e_2'=c_2^{-1}e_2e_2' \quad  (\text{using again the formula $B^{-1}=\det(B)^{-1}\text{adj}(B)$})$$

$$\implies R_ne_2e'_2R'_n\to  e_2e_2'$$

Reading off the diagonal this means that

$$|Q^{(2,2)}_n|\to 1, \quad Q^{(2,1)}_n\to 0, \quad Q^{(1,2)}_n\to 0$$

---

**Step 3.** Note that $\frac{1}{n}A_n\to e_1e_1'Ae_1e_1'=c_1e_1e_1'$ and $\frac{1}{n}Q_nV_nQ_n'-c_1Q_ne_1e_1'Q_n'\to 0$ which implies $Q_ne_1e_1'Q_n'\to e_1e_1'$ or $|Q^{(1,1)}_n|\to 1$.

---

We have shown that the off diagonal elements of $Q_n$ converge to zero while the diagonal elements of $Q_n$ converge to $1$ in absolute value. Therefore if we multiply column $j$ of $Q_n$ by $\text{sign}(Q_n^{(j,j)})$ we get $Q_n\to I_3$, as desired.

Is this correct? Is there an easier way to go about this?